# Playscape SDK 1.16 error on Editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

Playscape sdk v 1.16: In unity3d editor appear error from begin when was imported the sdk.
Seems is problem that the project is switched to **Android platform**, and the compiler don't found the *Playscape.Editor* library.

**Details in screenshots:**

[image: Console error]

[image: Error in script]

Comment: Write your exact error as text. This would make it possible to find your question over Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playscape sdk and FaceBook sdk issue when used toghether](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028050/playscape-sdk-and-facebook-sdk-issue-when-used-toghether)