# Playscape sdk and FaceBook sdk issue when used toghether

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

I upgraded to Unity 5 after I had to integrate FaceBook sdk. FB v7 or higher requires U5. But I have an error in console:

Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Internal/Configuration.cs(7,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Editor' does not exist in the namespace`Playscape'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Then I fallback to Unity 4.6.3 and tried Facebook sdk v 6.2.2 (which supports U4) and get a bunch of warnings. Seems that Playscape uses XCodeEditor-for-Unity and FB does have this too, with some differences in code.

And now I cant build anymore (after FB integration I have a build-time error about some classes was already added). Does Playscape sdk supports for Unity 5? How Can I make Playscape and FB be friends under U4?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved with PlayScape SDK 1.17. Please, check it.